# Given a List of Lists, return a Listh with Lists' length ( in another list)

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

When I try to run the following function, I get an error:

```
len' [] = 0
len' (_:xs) = 1 + len' xs

listlon [] = 0
listlon [[]] = 1
listlon (x:xs) = ((len' x):(listlon xs))
```

> functions.hs:41:1: error:
>      • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
>       (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>     • When checking the inferred type
>         listlon :: forall a t. (Num [a], Num a) => [[t]] -> [a]

Can some one explain me, How to fix this? What is this error conveying exactly?

Comment: Always use type signatures. They will make your intentions clear to the reader and yourself, and will help you understand the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
listlon [] = 0
```

produces the output `0` in place of something of type `[a]`. You most probably meant `listlon [] = []`. However I suggest `listlon = map length` or `listlon = map len'`. Or maybe I just do not understand what it is that you really want. As a first step, it always helps to provide the intended signature. Is it true that you are after a function `listlon :: [[a]] -> [Int]`?

If my understanding is correct, the most direct fix would be:

```
listlon [] = []
listlon [x] = [len' x]
listlon (x:xs) = len' x : listlon xs
```

This fixes the types. But you can notice that the second equation is redundant and this is sufficient

```
listlon [] = []
listlon (x:xs) = len' x : listlon xs
```

and now you can notice that this in fact is mapping `len'` over the list, hence `map len'` as the pointfree definition of `listlon`.

The error says that the compiler got confused about the return type. You are trying to return a `Num` by literals `0` and `1` as well as in form of a list (constructed by the last line). The constraint `Num [a]` is only possible using the extension `FlexibleContexts`. But in fact it only indicates the problem I described above. These kinds of error messages are sometimes confusing because the compiler cannot read your mind, and so it assumes you know what you are doing and only reports a problem when it cannot continue inferring types anymore due to some conflict.